How to create a provider that holds the state of the route at top of go_router?
I been trying to get riverpod to work with go_router via the observer field in the GoRouter Object. The objective is to create provider that other provider can read to retrieve the current route state.
However, the custom Observer is only observing the base root changes and does not trigger when shell route are pushed or popped.
import 'package:arcadia/router/routes.dart';
import 'package:logging/logging.dart';
import 'package:riverpod_annotation/riverpod_annotation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

part 'router.g.dart';


class MyNavObserver extends NavigatorObserver {

  MyNavObserver() {
    log.onRecord.listen((e) => debugPrint('$e'));
  }
  final log = Logger('MyNavObserver');

  @override
  void didPush(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic>? previousRoute){
    log.info('didPush: ${route.toString()}, previousRoute= ${previousRoute?.toString()}');
  }

  @override
  void didPop(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic>? previousRoute) =>
      log.info('didPop: ${route.toString()}, previousRoute= ${previousRoute?.toString()}');

  @override
  void didRemove(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic>? previousRoute) =>
      log.info('didRemove: ${route.toString()}, previousRoute= ${previousRoute?.toString()}');

  @override
  void didReplace({Route<dynamic>? newRoute, Route<dynamic>? oldRoute}) =>
      log.info('didReplace: new= ${newRoute?.toString()}, old= ${oldRoute?.toString()}');

  @override
  void didStartUserGesture(
    Route<dynamic> route,
    Route<dynamic>? previousRoute,
  ) =>
      log.info('didStartUserGesture: ${route.toString()}, '
          'previousRoute= ${previousRoute?.toString()}');

  @override
  void didStopUserGesture() => log.info('didStopUserGesture');
}


@riverpod
MyNavObserver routeObserver(ref) => MyNavObserver();


@riverpod
GoRouter router(RouterRef ref){
  final routerKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'routerKey');
  final routeObserver = ref.read(routeObserverProvider);



  final router = GoRouter(
    observers: [routeObserver],
    navigatorKey: routerKey,
    // refreshListenable: isAuth,
    initialLocation: const LoginRoute().location,
    debugLogDiagnostics: true,
    routes: $appRoutes,


  );
  ref.onDispose(router.dispose);

  return router;
}

The Routes
part 'routes.g.dart';

@TypedGoRoute<LoginRoute>(
  path: '/login'
  )
@immutable
class LoginRoute extends GoRouteData{
  const LoginRoute();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
    return const LoginScreen();
  }
}

// For ShellRoutes:
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> shellNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

@TypedShellRoute<MainAppShellRoute>(
  routes: <TypedRoute<RouteData>>[


    TypedGoRoute<MarketplaceGameSelectionRoute>(
      path: '/marketplace',
      routes: [
        TypedGoRoute<MarketplaceGameRoute>(
          path: 'game/:gameId',
        ),
        TypedGoRoute<MarketplaceSetRoute>(
          path: 'set/:setId'
        ),
        TypedGoRoute<MarketplaceProductRoute>(
          path: 'product/:productId'
        ),
        TypedGoRoute<MarketplaceUserRoute>(
          path: 'user/:userId'
        )
      ]
    ),
    TypedGoRoute<ShoppingCartRoute>(
      path: '/cart',
    ),

    TypedGoRoute<WishlistRoute>(
      path: '/wishlist',
    ), 



    TypedGoRoute<OpenOrderDashboardRoute>(
      path: '/orderbook',
      routes: [

        //Orderbook
        TypedGoRoute<OpenOrderBookOverviewRoute>(
          path: 'book',
        ),
        //Generic Request
        TypedGoRoute<OpenOrderRequestInstanceRoute>(
          path: 'request/:openOrderId',
          routes: [
            TypedGoRoute<OpenOrderRequestInstanceMakeOfferRoute>(
              path: 'make-offer',
            ),
          ]
        ),

        //My Requests
        TypedGoRoute<OpenOrderMyRequestsOverviewRoute>(
          path: 'my-requests',
          routes: [
            TypedGoRoute<OpenOrderMyRequestsDraftRoute>(
              path: 'draft/:gameName',
            ),
            TypedGoRoute<OpenOrderMyRequestsInstanceRoute>(
              path: ':openOrderId',
              routes: [
                TypedGoRoute<OpenOrderMyRequestsInstanceCompositionRoute>(
                  path: 'composition',
                ),
                TypedGoRoute<OpenOrderMyRequestsInstanceOfferInstanceRoute>(
                  path: ':offerId',
                ),
              ]
            )
          ]
        ),

        //My Offers
        TypedGoRoute<OpenOrderMyOffersOverviewRoute>(
          path: 'my-offers',
          routes: [
            TypedGoRoute<OpenOrderMyOffersInstanceRoute>(
              path: ':openOrderId/:offerId',
            )
          ]
        ),
      ]
    ),
    

    TypedGoRoute<ChatRoute>(
      path: '/user/update',
    ),


    TypedGoRoute<ProfileRoute>(
      path: '/user/profile',
      routes: [
        TypedGoRoute<PurchaseStatusSelectionRoute>(
          path: 'purchase-status',
          routes: [
            TypedGoRoute<ToPayPurchaseStatusSelectionRoute>(
              path: 'to-pay',
            ),
            TypedGoRoute<ToShipPurchaseStatusSelectionRoute>(
              path: 'to-ship',
            ),
            TypedGoRoute<ToRecievePurchaseStatusSelectionRoute>(
              path: 'to-recieve',
            ),
            TypedGoRoute<CompletedPurchaseStatusSelectionRoute>(
              path: 'completed',
            ),
          ]
        ),
        TypedGoRoute<SettingLocationRoute>(
          path: 'settings/location',
        ),
        TypedGoRoute<SettingLanguageRoute>(
          path: 'settings/langauge',
        ),
        TypedGoRoute<SettingCurrencyRoute>(
          path: 'settings/currency',
        ),
        TypedGoRoute<SettingPaymentMethodRoute>(
          path: 'settings/payment-method',
        ),
        TypedGoRoute<SettingPasswordResetRoute>(
          path: 'settings/password-reset',
        ),
      ]
    ), 
  ],
)
@immutable
class MainAppShellRoute  extends ShellRouteData {
  const MainAppShellRoute();

  static final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> $navigatorKey = shellNavigatorKey;

  @override
  Widget builder(BuildContext context, GoRouterState state, Widget navigator) {
    return MainAppScreen(page: navigator);
  } 
}

The logs produced by above code:

go_router's logging but not observer logging
only observation log recorded

Referencing -> Flutter: how to listen to GoRouter's route / location changes in a Riverpod provider?
followed the 1# answer provided by Michele; Can't implement due to The argument type 'AutoDisposeProvider<GoRouter>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'AlwaysAliveProviderListenable<InvalidType>'. error.
trying not use the 2# answer to refractor. Nuclear Option as of now.
